# Reverse image search for scientific plot (image file), to identify the original article

Tags: image, image-processing, reverse-engineering

I have an image file with the following plot:
[image]

The plot comes from a scientific article, but I do not know any details of it (journal, authors, even the general field of research, other than it was probably related to social- or life-sciences). I would very much like to find the paper so I can have a closer look at what the plotted variables represent.

I did a reverse search with this image on Google Images, but that didn't help locate the original article. (I only got suggestions for similar images)

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: TinEye doesn't know it https://tineye.com/search/e0dbd34b78e111bb9404cdce69427fed6b18baed?page=1

Comment: I guess it might be that said paper is behind some journal's paywall then